# How to draw a line between points in google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, path, overlay

I already wrote a program that read locations from android GPS ; each locatin(long , lat) will be sent to remote server to save it and display it in a website map.

what I'm trying to do now is to display my path in android by drawing line between the points
I didn't find any sufficient answer until this moment!  so how this can be done?

Comment: In Maps, if you go to menu > Labs, there is a feature called Measure that allows you to draw lines. It's made for users, but perhaps you could investigate manipulating that programmatically

Comment: Thanx , but I couldn't find any Maps tab in Eclipse 
so is it a feature in Eclipse? or another program called maps?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw line between points as:

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when)
        {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false)
        {
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
      paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

      Point point = new Point();
      projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
      /* mode=1 create the starting point */
      if(mode==1)
      {
          RectF oval=new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y - mRadius,
                             point.x + mRadius, point.y + mRadius);
        /* draw the circle with the starting point  */
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
      }
      /* mode=2 draw the route line */
      else if(mode==2)
      {
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setAlpha(120);
        /* draw the lint */
        canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
      }
      /* mode=3 create the ending point */
      else if(mode==3)
      {
        /* draw the line of the last part firstly to avoid error */
        Point point2 = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setAlpha(120);
        canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
        /* define the RectF object */
        RectF oval=new RectF(point2.x - mRadius,point2.y - mRadius,
                             point2.x + mRadius,point2.y + mRadius);
        /* draw the circle with the ending point */
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
      }
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
  }
```